# mobile "push" page in web browser - how?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile page, js-library only for DOM and events (zepto), no fancy ui-library.

Now I want to add some kind of "modal" feature. Thinking of scroll-right "push",
where the the loaded content pans out to the left. On finish, pop the original page back.

Since the first page is width=100% I can't find any solid solution to work this out. Thankful for any solid css-tricks on this one.

regards,
//t

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS transforms to move the content out of the way.

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say, but if I were doing this I'd make a div wide enough to hold the page content + the modal bit, put them both in the div and float them both right.

I'd then absolutely position the big div so you could only see the content. When I needed a modal I'd put it's content into the off screen div, then transform the big div to slide it into view.

Of course, without seeing any of your code, that might be impossible, but it's hardware accelerated, and can only involve adding and removing classes to get the animation.